# Word Problems regarding Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, word-problem

This post is going to be lengthy. I am studying Probability to recall my knowledge about it before I take a class in Stats this college. The thing is, the textbook I have didn't provide any solution which could help me determine if my answers were correct or not. Anyway, here are the problems with their respective solutions I have made:

$1.$ In how many ways can a librarian arrange $2$ Biology and $5$ Math books in a shelf?

> **My attempt:** $2$ Bio books $\times$ $5$ Math books = $10$ ways

$2.$ How many $2$-letter words can you form using letters $w,x,y,z$ without repeating letters?

> **My attempt:** 4!/2! = 12

$3.$ How many ways can $5$ questions be answered if for every question there are $3$ possible answers?

> **My attempt:** 5 x 3 = 15
>
> 15! is the answer, I guess.

$4.$ There are $3$ math books and $3$ history books that are to be arranged in a shelf. How many different ways can the books be arranged on the shelf if $2$ history books are also to be kept together and $2$ mathematics books are also to be kept together? The $2$ math books should be immediately followed by the $2$ history books, and vice versa.

> I have no idea how to tackle this one. The load of words confuse me.
> I'm guessing it's $5 \times 5$? Since both $2$ books for history and math are
> to be kept together.

$5.$ Cinderella and her $7$ dwarves will eat in a round table. Happy wishes not to be seated opposite Grumpy. What's the probability that things will not work out for Happy?

> **My attempt:** (7-1)! = 6!

Thank you in advance. Any help will mean a lot.

Comment: Counting problems are called combinatorics problems.

Answer (score 2):

### Ok, here we go!

**I'll give you some answers and working, and leave some for you:**

---

1. This depends on the wording. If the books are all distinct, then there are $7! = 7*6*5*4*3*2*1 = 5040$ arrangements. But, if bio books are identical and math books are identical, there are$ \frac{7!}{5!*2!} = \frac{5040}{240} =$ **21**.

---

2. There are 4 options for the first letter, 3 for the second so since $4\times3$ = **12**, you are correct.

---

3. For the first question there are 3 options, second 3 options, 3rd 3 options... so the total will be $3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3$ = $3^5$ = **243 possibilities.**

---

4. Assuming you mean we have two math books followed by two history books or vice versa, we can place this block of 4 books amongst the 6 spaces we can order them in. **Assuming Math books are identical and history books are identical,** we have the following possibilities (blank spaces represent where we can place the other books):

(4-block)-- = 2 possibilities to place the 2 remaining books in the remaining spaces

-(4-block)- = 2 possibilities to place the 2 remaining books in the remaining spaces

--(4-block) = 2 possibilities to place the 2 remaining books in the remaining spaces

So total 6, but we can arrange it within the 4-block as history first then math or math first then history so multiply by 2: **12 is the answer**.

---

1. Firstly, this asks for the probability, not the possibility. I've given you some tips on the other one so I'll leave this for you to try and figure out, here's a hint:

> First seat Happy and look then what are the possibilities left for Grumpy to seat.

---

**N.B:**
*In case you want to learn, look up combinatorics - covering combinations, arrangements and permutations. Its a fascinating field.*

---

***Good luck!***

---

Comment: Don't you think the last one is simpler than you suggest? Or am I wrong to think so?

Comment: I simply suggested what was left in the comments... I haven't attempted to solve it to allow Janine to have a go at it.

Comment: Okay, that's fine to do so, but I think it might misguide Janine.

Comment: I suggested an edit. If you disagree with it, feel free not to change your post.

Comment: No problem. Done.

Comment: The product $7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1$ was not rendered properly since you did not put it in math mode.  You could type `$7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$` to produce $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In the fourth problem, you seem to be assuming that the mathematics books are identical and the history books are identical without specifying that is what you are doing.

Comment: Ah, sorry bout the formatting @N.F.Taussig - I know how to do it, using \times in Q3, just forgot for 7!

Comment: And true, for Q4